# Search through folders/subfolders faster

Tags: excel, vba, performance, search, sharepoint

I'm trying to search multiple folders on our Sharepoint site and their subfolders for Excel documents matching some criteria, then copy data from the workbooks into a summary book (don't really need help with that part). I've searched all over, and came up with the following code, but it is ridiculously slow (I have close to 1000 folders each with multiple subfolders to look through). I'm curious if anyone knows a faster way since this can run all weekend, and still not be even close.

```
Sub Main()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed, FileString As String
Const MyDir As String = "\\hp.sharepoint.com@SSL\..."

' Remember time macro starts
StartTime = Timer

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set queue = New Collection
queue.Add fso.GetFolder(MyDir)

Do While queue.Count > 0
    Set oFolder = queue(1)
    queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
    For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
    Next oSubfolder
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        FileString = fso.GetFileName(oFile)
        If InStr(FileString, "FAI") > 0 Then
            Call FAI(oFile) ' Copies data from files
        ElseIf InStr(FileString, "CPK") > 0 Then
            Call CPK(oFile) ' Copies data from files
        End If
    Next oFile
Loop

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

'Determine how long code took to run
MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
Debug.Print "This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed, vbInformation

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume Next

End Sub
```